# LibGDX - ImageTextButton - Alignment

Tags: libgdx, alignment

I created an ImageTextButton in LibGDX:

```
    _rewardedVideo = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menus/blue.png"));
    _rewardedVideo.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    _rewardedVideoPressed = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menus/bluePressed.png"));
    _rewardedVideoPressed.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    _symbolRewardedVideo = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menus/symbolRewardedVideo.png"));
    _symbolRewardedVideo.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle styleRewardedVideo = new ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle();
    styleRewardedVideo.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(_rewardedVideo));
    styleRewardedVideo.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(_rewardedVideoPressed));
    styleRewardedVideo.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(_symbolRewardedVideo));
    styleRewardedVideo.font = skin.getFont("large-font");
    styleRewardedVideo.fontColor = Color.WHITE;

    buttonRewardedVideo = new ImageTextButton("WATCH VIDEO", styleRewardedVideo);
    buttonRewardedVideo.setPosition(580, 180);
    buttonRewardedVideo.setSize(450, 80);
    // The last two lines do not work:
    buttonRewardedVideo.getLabel().setAlignment(Align.left);
    buttonRewardedVideo.getImage().setAlign(Align.right);
```

I was hoping the button would contain a left-aligned label and a right-aligned image. But it was the opposite:
https://i.ibb.co/QCZPqT8/Image-Text-Button.png

What's wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ImageTextButton` is a `Table`, if you look the class it adds first the `Image` and then the `Label`...

```
public ImageTextButton (String text, ImageTextButtonStyle style) {
    super(style);
    this.style = style;

    defaults().space(3);

    image = new Image();
    image.setScaling(Scaling.fit);

    label = new Label(text, new LabelStyle(style.font, style.fontColor));
    label.setAlignment(Align.center);

    add(image);
    add(label);

    setStyle(style);

    setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
}
```

You can create your own class which would be a copy of `ImageTextButton` and just swap those lines or just clear the table and re-add the items like so...

```
buttonRewardedVideo = new ImageTextButton("WATCH VIDEO", styleRewardedVideo);

buttonRewardedVideo.clearChildren();
buttonRewardedVideo.add(buttonRewardedVideo.getLabel());
buttonRewardedVideo.add(buttonRewardedVideo.getImage());

buttonRewardedVideo.setPosition(580, 180);
buttonRewardedVideo.setSize(450, 80);
```